# RSelenium sendKeysToActiveElement() function throws unknown command error

Tags: r, selenium-webdriver, rselenium

I'm trying to press enter key using the RSelenium's `sendKeysToActiveElement()` function but it's throwing 
the following error.

`remDr$sendKeysToActiveElement(list("", key="back"))`

It throws the following error:

```
Selenium message:sendKeysToActiveElement
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:53'
System info: host: 'DEV-WINDOWS', ip: '192.168.1.18', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_201'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown

Error:   Summary: UnknownCommand
     Detail: The requested resource could not be found, or a request was received using an HTTP method that is not supported by the mapped resource.
     Further Details: run errorDetails method
```

This is what `errorDetails() shows`:

```
remDr$errorDetails()
$stacktrace
[1] "org.openqa.selenium.UnsupportedCommandException: sendKeysToActiveElement\nBuild info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:53'\nSystem info: host: 'DEV-WINDOWS', ip: '192.168.1.18', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_201'\nDriver info: driver.version: unknown\r\n\tat org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.AbstractHttpCommandCodec.encode(AbstractHttpCommandCodec.java:218)\r\n\tat org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.AbstractHttpCommandCodec.encode(AbstractHttpCommandCodec.java:117)\r\n\tat org.openqa.selenium.grid.session.remote.ProtocolConverter.handle(ProtocolConverter.java:83)\r\n\tat org.openqa.selenium.grid.session.remote.RemoteSession.execute(RemoteSession.java:129)\r\n\tat org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.WebDriverServlet.lambda$handle$0(WebDriverServlet.java:235)\r\n\tat java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)\r\n\tat java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)\r\n\tat java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)\r\n\tat java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)\r\n\tat java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)\r\n"

$stackTrace
$stackTrace[[1]]
$stackTrace[[1]]$fileName
[1] "AbstractHttpCommandCodec.java"

$stackTrace[[1]]$methodName
[1] "encode"

$stackTrace[[1]]$className
[1] "org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.AbstractHttpCommandCodec"

$stackTrace[[1]]$lineNumber
[1] 218


$stackTrace[[2]]
$stackTrace[[2]]$fileName
[1] "AbstractHttpCommandCodec.java"

$stackTrace[[2]]$methodName
[1] "encode"

$stackTrace[[2]]$className
[1] "org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.AbstractHttpCommandCodec"

$stackTrace[[2]]$lineNumber
[1] 117


$stackTrace[[3]]
$stackTrace[[3]]$fileName
[1] "ProtocolConverter.java"

$stackTrace[[3]]$methodName
[1] "handle"

$stackTrace[[3]]$className
[1] "org.openqa.selenium.grid.session.remote.ProtocolConverter"

$stackTrace[[3]]$lineNumber
[1] 83


$stackTrace[[4]]
$stackTrace[[4]]$fileName
[1] "RemoteSession.java"

$stackTrace[[4]]$methodName
[1] "execute"

$stackTrace[[4]]$className
[1] "org.openqa.selenium.grid.session.remote.RemoteSession"

$stackTrace[[4]]$lineNumber
[1] 129


$stackTrace[[5]]
$stackTrace[[5]]$fileName
[1] "WebDriverServlet.java"

$stackTrace[[5]]$methodName
[1] "lambda$handle$0"

$stackTrace[[5]]$className
[1] "org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.WebDriverServlet"

$stackTrace[[5]]$lineNumber
[1] 235


$stackTrace[[6]]
$stackTrace[[6]]$fileName
[1] "Executors.java"

$stackTrace[[6]]$methodName
[1] "call"

$stackTrace[[6]]$className
[1] "java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter"

$stackTrace[[6]]$lineNumber
[1] 511


$stackTrace[[7]]
$stackTrace[[7]]$fileName
[1] "FutureTask.java"

$stackTrace[[7]]$methodName
[1] "run"

$stackTrace[[7]]$className
[1] "java.util.concurrent.FutureTask"

$stackTrace[[7]]$lineNumber
[1] 266


$stackTrace[[8]]
$stackTrace[[8]]$fileName
[1] "ThreadPoolExecutor.java"

$stackTrace[[8]]$methodName
[1] "runWorker"

$stackTrace[[8]]$className
[1] "java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor"

$stackTrace[[8]]$lineNumber
[1] 1149


$stackTrace[[9]]
$stackTrace[[9]]$fileName
[1] "ThreadPoolExecutor.java"

$stackTrace[[9]]$methodName
[1] "run"

$stackTrace[[9]]$className
[1] "java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker"

$stackTrace[[9]]$lineNumber
[1] 624


$stackTrace[[10]]
$stackTrace[[10]]$fileName
[1] "Thread.java"

$stackTrace[[10]]$methodName
[1] "run"

$stackTrace[[10]]$className
[1] "java.lang.Thread"

$stackTrace[[10]]$lineNumber
[1] 748


$message
[1] "sendKeysToActiveElement\nBuild info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:53'\nSystem info: host: 'DEV-WINDOWS', ip: '192.168.1.18', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_201'\nDriver info: driver.version: unknown"

$error
[1] "unknown command"
```

`sessionInfo()` shows following:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.0.0 (2020-04-24)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 18363)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_India.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_India.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_India.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                  
[5] LC_TIME=English_India.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods  
[7] base     

other attached packages:
[1] knitr_1.28        XML_3.99-0.3      RSelenium_1.7.7  
[4] animint2_2020.3.2 testthat_2.3.2   

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.4.6     compiler_4.0.0   plyr_1.8.6      
 [4] bitops_1.0-6     tools_4.0.0      pkgload_1.1.0   
 [7] digest_0.6.25    jsonlite_1.6.1   evaluate_0.14   
[10] lifecycle_0.2.0  gtable_0.3.0     rlang_0.4.6     
[13] cli_2.0.2        rstudioapi_0.11  curl_4.3        
[16] yaml_2.2.1       xfun_0.14        binman_0.1.1    
[19] stringr_1.4.0    withr_2.2.0      httr_1.4.1      
[22] xml2_1.3.2       desc_1.2.0       askpass_1.1     
[25] caTools_1.18.0   rappdirs_0.3.1   rprojroot_1.3-2 
[28] grid_4.0.0       glue_1.4.1       R6_2.4.1        
[31] processx_3.4.2   fansi_0.4.1      rmarkdown_2.2   
[34] RJSONIO_1.3-1.4  farver_2.0.3     semver_0.2.0    
[37] magrittr_1.5     backports_1.1.7  scales_1.1.1    
[40] ps_1.3.3         htmltools_0.4.0  assertthat_0.2.1
[43] colorspace_1.4-1 labeling_0.3     stringi_1.4.6   
[46] openssl_1.4.1    munsell_0.5.0    crayon_1.3.4    
[49] wdman_0.2.5
```

Comment: Could you provide the part of the code just before the error.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to check StackOverflow over time.
The issue was actually caused by using the wrong version of selenium. I missed the documentation of RSelenium mentioning that it used v2 only but I used v3 instead.

Using v2 solved the issue.

Comment: @lazycipher how did you set up the version ? I am struggling with this issue for days...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what RSelenium documentation says:

> This is a set of R Bindings for Selenium 2.0 Remote WebDriver, which you can download from http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/index.html. This binding will not work with the 1.0 version of Selenium.

Due do major changes in selenium v3, this function didn't work.

I was using the wrong version of selenium. I used v3 instead of v2.

Changing the selenium version solved the issue.

Comment: maybe posting the code you used would be more helpful

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same issue, and @lazycipher suggests, downgrading the selenium version helped. I did this by:

1. Go to http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/index.html
2. Navigate to the `2.53` folder
3. Download `selenium-server-standalone-2.53.1.jar`
4. Move the `jar` file to a folder in the following location:

   - Linux: `/home/[user]/.local/share/binman_seleniumserver/generic/2.53.1`
   - Windows: `C:\Users\[user]\AppData\Local\binman\binman_seleniumserver\generic\2.53.1\`
   - MACOSX: `/Users/admin/Library/Application\Support/binman_seleniumserver/generic/2.53.1/`
5. Check whether the downloaded version is listed using `binman::list_versions("seleniumserver")`
6. Run `RSelenium::rsDriver()` with the `version = '2.53.1'` argument

It turns out, when `RSelenium::rsDriver()` accesses the selenium version, it refers to the `binman` package to direct it to the correct selenium jar file. If you place the jar file in the right folder, it'll be detected by `binman` and, consequently, by `RSelenium`.